# adding new nodes at head

Tags: c++, nodes

Pardon me. I am new to C++. I tried to add the third node as the the head node and initialize 5 for the data but it seems that it destory the pervious linklist of 1->2.

so current output only on outputs

```
5
```

and my expected output will be

```
5
1
2
```

what I have tried.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
   int data;
   node *next;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    node* n;
    node * head;
    node * tmp;

    //create head node.
    n = new node;
    n->data=1;
    tmp = n;
    head = n;

    //create a new node after head node and link it with head node
    n = new node;
    n->data=2;
    tmp->next=n;
    tmp=tmp->next;

    //inserting before head node
    n = new node;
    head = n;
    n->data=5;
    n->next = head;
    tmp = head;

   //end of linked list
   n->next=NULL;

   //print
   while ( head != NULL ) {
        std::cout<< head->data << std::endl;
        head = head->next;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create an `InsertNode()` function so you won't have to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem,but it not a good way to write list.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
   int data;
   node *next;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    node* n;
    node * head;
    node * tmp;

    //create head node.
    n = new node;
    n->data=1;
    tmp = n;
    head = n;

    //create a new node after head node and link it with head node
    n = new node;
    n->data=2;
    tmp->next=n;
    tmp=tmp->next;

    //inserting before head node(the following i have changed!)
    n = new node;
    n->data=5;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;

   //end of linked list
   tmp=NULL;

   //print
   while ( head != NULL ) {
        std::cout<< head->data << std::endl;
        head = head->next;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line sets the `next` of the *first* node to `NULL`, not the last one:

```
//end of linked list
n->next=NULL;
```

Additionally, you do assign the `next` of `n` to itself:

```
 head = n;
 n->next = head;
```

You should set the `next` of `n` before reassigning `head`.

If you want to set the last node's `next`, use something like:

```
 n->next->next->next = NULL;
```

However, you would be better off using constructors to initialize the data and writing member functions to manipulate the data rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not creating a linked list. You are inserting at head, overwriting the head pointer before chaining the existing list to the new node, thus destroying the whole list.

Try that:

```
struct node {
  int x;
  node *next;
};

int main()
{
  node *root;       // This won't change, or we would lose the list in memory
  node *conductor;  // This will point to each node as it traverses the list

  root = new node;  // Sets it to actually point to something
  root->next = 0;   //  Otherwise it would not work well
  root->x = 12;
  conductor = root; // The conductor points to the first node
  if ( conductor != 0 ) {
    while ( conductor->next != 0)
      conductor = conductor->next;
  }
  conductor->next = new node;  // Creates a node at the end of the list
  conductor = conductor->next; // Points to that node
  conductor->next = 0;         // Prevents it from going any further
  conductor->x = 42;
}
```

Comment: Your opening statement is not true. OP is creating new nodes and inserting them at tmp correctly. OP's insert at head code overwrites the head pointer before chaining the existing list to the new node, destroying the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet

```
    //inserting before head node
    n = new node;
    head = n;
    n->data=5;
    n->next = head;
    tmp = head;

   //end of linked list
   n->next=NULL;
```

does not make sense.

You assigned n to head.

```
    head = n;
```

and then assigned data member next to the address of the node itself because head is already equal to n.

```
    n->next = head;
```

After that you reassigned n->next

```
   n->next=NULL;
```

Thus now node head has data member next that equal to NULL and in fact your list contains only the head.

The program can be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
   int data;
   node *next;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    node * n;
    node * head = NULL;
    node * tail = NULL;

    //create head node.
    n = new node;
    n->data = 1;
    n->next = NULL;
    tail = n;
    head = n;

    //create a new node after head node and link it with head node
    n = new node;
    n->data = 2;
    n->next = NULL;

    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;

    //inserting before head node
    n = new node;
    n->data = 5;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;

   //print
   for ( n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next ) {
        std::cout<< n->data << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick explanation of why assigning n to head, just overwrote the entry node into the list and lost the list, would enhance this answer greatly.